# Chrome Remote Interface Error: Unknown command: protocol

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, chrome-remote-debugging

I was trying to use [chrome-remote-interface](https://github.com/cyrus-and/chrome-remote-interface) sample in windows, but unable to produce the result with an error

> Error: Unknown command: protocol

```
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (..\node_modules\chrome-remote-interface\lib\external-request.js:29:30)
at emitNone (events.js:110:20)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:207:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1059:12)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

This is the specs of my machine :

- Google Chrome Version 66.0.3359.181 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Windows 10

Comment: Have you found any solution? I'm dealing with the same.